# Use of undeclared type 'MainGameScreenViewController'

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Hello all I had a strange problem last night in my project even if I didnt make any changes in my GameScreenViewController.swift class, its show me the use of undeclared type 'UIViewController' In code

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework
import RealmSwift
import AVFoundation

class GameScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, PlayerInformationCellTableViewCellDelegate {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mainGameScreen"{
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! MainGameScreenViewController
        for item in tempPlayers{
            nextVC.playerArray.append(item)
        }
    }
}

}
```

MainGameScreenViewController.swit

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import ChameleonFramework
import AVFoundation


class MainGameScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerArray: [Player] = [] //container for the player

}
```

full error is `Use of undeclared type 'MainGameScreenViewController'`

Can any one help me? I read some kind of question as I encountered but nothing solved mine.

Comment: Did you properly check file's target ?

Comment: What is that mean ?

Comment: The file have to be included to the build target. Otherwise,  this class is invisible for your app

Comment: Okay so I will try to find this setting Can you give some path for this ?

Comment: Thanks for answer its done I got it can you write as an answer pls ? @Vyacheslav

Comment: I've written the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to include the file where you wrote missed class to the corresponding target. Just enable checkbox in the right panel of the XCode when you open the file.